# jQuery UI - change submit function

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, jquery-ui

I have a jquery dialog, which load a form and on submit button, it submits the form

```
    dialog = $("#dialog-form").dialog({
        autoOpen: false,
        height: 440,
        width: 420,
        modal: true,
        buttons: {
            "Submit": function () {
                $("#LogOnForm").submit();
            },
            "Cancel": function () {
                $(this).dialog("close");
            }
        }
    });
```

Assume #LogOnForm is simple form with few text fields.

Now i have decided to use jquery tab within the dialog which loads multiple forms and based on the selected tab the appropriate form should be called

```
$("#tabs").bind("tabsselect", function (event, ui) {
        switch (ui.index) {
            case 0:
                //Change the submit function
                break;

            case 1:
               //Change the submit function
                break;
        }
```

My question is how to change the submit function based on the tab selected?

I have gone through a few work around like as [suggested here](https://www.google.com.sg/?gfe_rd=cr&ei=x_EwVJntD4iFoAPS8YHwDQ#q=jquery+ui+dialog+change+submit+button+function).

Any suggestion on an elegant way to do this?

Comment: Couldn't you just unbind the existing submit event and add your new submit event on tab change?

Comment: I cant get the id on the button. Yes, one way is to add the id and the in code, unbind/bind as suggested in the link in the question. Is there a way like to get the dialog's object and change the event?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this..

```
var formid;

$("#tabs").bind("tabsselect", function (event, ui) {
    switch (ui.index) {
        case 0:
            formid = '#form1';
            break;

        case 1:
           //Change the submit function
            break;
    }

$(formid).submit();
```

Comment: Yes, eventually i went with something like "selectedForm = $("#LogOnForm")" and "selectedForm = $("#RegisterForm")" in the cases. Is working well as of now.